# Angular 4/2 application hosting on IIS

Tags: angular, web-hosting, iis-10

I am trying to host my Angular 4 application on IIS 10 and it's working fine when 
redirect to one route to another by clicking on any link inside application but when I type same link in URL its i get 404 error message.

I have gone through angular documents and it say that i have t create a fallback to index.html which i did using URL Re write on IIS level, it didn't work.

My hosted application URL is http://localhost:86/

Here is the structure of my application folder which is added as website in IIS:
[image]

Base href is `<base href="/">`

is there anything wrong?

One more thing, is it by using this fallback user will not able to type url as it will re-directed to index.html?

Comment: could you try with base href="./"?

Comment: try to set  in webconfig deault page to index.html

Comment: it did not work?

Comment: try configuring the routerModule to useHash:true

Comment: Can you share your URL Rewrite config on IIS

Comment: @faderico scamuzzi i was not configuring my rule correctly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it needs to be done in webconfig of hosted app.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Just replace this with content of web config and consider action tag url. Mine base url was "/".

Thanks